# Help with scientific notation formatting

Tags: notation

I do apologize if this is a frequent topic, but after browsing and reading some of the linked questions when typing in my title, I can still not figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am receiving 20 out of 24 points for this question, so clearly I am either wrong, or I don't understand the format of the fields.

So, is one of my answers indeed wrong? Or am I just not entering the answer in the way that it is asking for?

**edit:** well I feel stupid lol, after looking at this for over half an hour, I just realized it said to leave commas out of excel but include them in the answer on blackboard. Will try and report back.

[image: scientific notation question]

[image: scientific notation excel work]

**edit 2:** okay so I added commas and that did help a little bit, but now getting 22 out of 24 points, and I am truly stumped this time.

[image]

Comment: Are you missing a minus sign in the third row within the "Ordinary Notation" column?  The -2.5...?  I might be misunderstanding, but possible issue.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! I feel so stupid haha. I was for some reason thinking that since I was going right with the counting the number became positive. And that it would only be negative if counting to the left. Obviously this makes no sense in hindsight, but my brain kept glossing over that i guess. Thanks so much!